# Picking elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list,

```
t = {{"e:r", "a", "p", "z"}, {"r:e", "a", "l", "o", "t", "y", 
    "z"}, {"j", "o", "z"}};
```

I want to go through it and pick the elements that have `"e:r"` or `"r:e"` they are the same in fact I just put it this way so the final code would be applied to any orderless system. To do this I made the following:

```
mod = {{"e:r"}};
tmp = Table[SubsetQ[mod, t[[i]]], {i, Length[t]}];
make = Pick[t, tmp];
```

But this does not work, am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I can use

```
Select[ContainsAny@{"e:r", "r:e"}]@t
```

But how can I just use `"r:e"` or `"e:r"` and the program would understand they are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cc = Total[ToCharacterCode["e:r"]];
Pick[t, 1 - Unitize[Total[ToCharacterCode[t[[All, 1]]], {2}] - cc], 1]
```

> {{"e:r", "a", "p", "z"}, {"r:e", "a", "l", "o", "t", "y", "z"}}